# Class isn't trivially_copyable if a constraint on its assignment operator is not satisfied with clang 16

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug, trivially-copyable

Example code as below or on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dzorGb68o). clang 16/trunk believes `S<int>` is not a `trivially_copyable` class. clang 15, gcc trunk and MSVC believe otherwise.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct S {
    T m_t;
    S(S const&) = default;
    S(S&&) = default;
    S& operator=(S const&) requires (!std::is_integral<T>::value) = default;
    ~S() = default;
};

// next five assertions pass for all compilers
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<S<int>>::value);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<S<int>>::value);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible<S<int>>::value);
static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable<S<int>>::value);
static_assert(!std::is_move_assignable<S<int>>::value);

// compiles with gcc trunk, MSVC and clang 15, fails with clang 16/trunk
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<S<int>>::value);
```

According to the standard [class.prop](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.prop#1):

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor,    copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator ([special],
>   [class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]),
> - where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy    assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial, and
> - that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor ([class.dtor]).

`S<int>` has trivial copy/move constructor and trivial destructor. Its copy/move assignment operators are not eligible. I would agree with gcc/MSVC/clang15 on this. Is clang 16/trunk wrong on this one or am I missing something?

Edit: This is a confirmed [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/63352).

Comment: Yes this class is trivially copyable

Comment: @DanielLangr The copy assignment operator is not eligible because the constraint is not satisfied. move assignment operator is not eligible because it's deleted. copy/move constructors are eligible and trivial. It looks like a trivially copyable class to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `S<int>` is trivially copyable. It looks like you've discovered a clang bug. I was unable to find it in:

- [the GitHub list of llvm-project issues](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues)
- [the LLVM Bugzilla buck tracker](https://bugs.llvm.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=trivially_copyable)

So this may be a new regression.

#### Proof for `S<int>` being trivially copyable

It's worth examining what *elegible* means:

> An eligible special member function is a special member function for which:
>
> - the function is not deleted,
> - **the associated constraints ([temp.constr]), if any, are satisfied, and**
> - no special member function of the same kind is more constrained ([temp.constr.order]).

- [[class.prop] §1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.prop#1)

```cpp
S& operator=(S const&) requires (!std::is_integral<T>::value) = default
```

This copy assignment operator is user-declared (and not user-provided) and its constraints aren't satisfied, so it is not eligible. Furthermore:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - [...]

- [[class.copy.assign] $4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.copy.assign#4)

This means that:

- the copy-assignment operator is user-declared, but not eligible
- the move-assignment operator is not declared

All of the remaining (eligible) special member functions are trivial, therefore `S<int>` is trivially copyable.